# how to drop job with lowercase name ORACLE (=> ORA-27475 )

Tags: oracle, jobs

How can I drop a job with lowercase name in Oracle?

It gives me an error ORA-27475 "JOB_NAME" must be a job

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.stop_job(job_name => 'MY_JOB_name');
END;
/
```

The job exists for sure .. do you know how to circumvent this issue?

Thx

Comment: Did you try including owner name as well? `'OWNER.MY_JOB_NAME'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to work with case-sensitive identifiers, you need to put them between double quotation marks, otherwise the database handles them as case-insensitive and automatically converts to uppercase.

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job
  (
   job_name             => '"job1"',
   job_type             => 'plsql_block',
   job_action           => 'begin null; end;'
  );
end;
/

select job_name from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'job1';

JOB_NAME                      
------------------------------
job1
```

This fails:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job('job1');
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-27475: "BP.JOB1" must be a job
...
```

But this works:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job('"job1"');
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: thx a million :)